# What are "the twos"?

Tags: american-english

I am a British English native speaker, and I've heard a few references in American media to broadcasts of "*x* (typically traffic) on the 2s". Google does not reveal any useful information on exactly what this phrase is meant to *mean*, so I'm hoping an American English speaker can clarify for mine and the internet's sake.

I have a few theories:

- Traffic (or news or whatever) reports hourly at 2 or 22 minutes past the hour, or every two hours, or at 2AM and 2PM daily, or at 22:00 daily
- Television affiliates with a number two in their title using the title of the broadcast as a way to push their brand
- Traffic reports in reference to a specific route/interstate matching, both of which bearing the designator of #2

Comment: Every ten minutes:  10:02, 10:12, 10:22, 10:32...

Comment: [Commonly, a station will promote its traffic report by broadcasting it **every ten minutes** “on the 3s" or "on the 1s."](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22Commonly%2C+a+station+will+promote+its+traffic+report+by+broadcasting+it%22&oq=%22Commonly%2C+a+station+will+promote+its+traffic+report+by+broadcasting+it%22&aqs=chrome..69i57.2551j0j8&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) But I also found [WKST-TV moved to the stronger channel 33 in 1959, improving its over-the-air ... Originally called "Weather on the 3s", the channel shows continuous weather...](https://wikivisually.com/wiki/WYTV).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Local on the 8s.

> Local on the 8s (or the Local Forecast) is a program segment that airs on the American cable and satellite television network The Weather Channel. It provides viewers with information on current and forecasted weather conditions for their respective area; a version of this segment is also available on the channel's national satellite feed that features forecasts for each region of the United States. The name "Local on the 8s" comes from the timing of the segment, as airs at timeslots that end in "8" (examples: 9:18 and 12:48); because of this manner of scheduling, the forecast segments air on the channel in ten-minute intervals. From 2006-2013, each forecast segment has usually been preceded by a promo for one of The Weather Channel's programs or services, leading into the segment with the announcer stating "And now, your Local on the 8s". On November 12, 2013 the promo segment was replaced by an intro that was built into the Local on the 8s segment.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_on_the_8s